# Azure Linux VM Captured, Built from image. Different password or key for new VM: permission denied?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, ubuntu-12.04, azure

I followed [How to Capture an Image of a Virtual Machine Running Linux](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/) to capture a VM image, after installing the packages I wanted on top of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I turned off the machine following a `waagent -deprovision` and Captured the image.

When I had created the first VM (which I later captured), I specified a certificate file `key1.pem`.

When I created a new VM from the My Images image, I specified a certificate file `key2.pem`.

When I attempted to connect to the new VM, I received the message `Permission denied (public key).`. To connect, I used `ssh -i ssh/key2 -p myport azureuser@myservice.cloudapp.net`.

What's wrong? Are there special steps needed to use a different key than was used in the template image? Is this a bug?

Comment: the key is used when certs are generated.  if you switch the key without regenerating the related certs, I think this is the expected behavior.

Comment: I created a new VM from the Captured image, and uploaded a new cert, generated from the new key, as part of the creation process of the new VM. I would expect to be able to authenticate using the key used in this creation process.

Comment: oh i thought you were talking about the server's ssh key.  If it's your own key, maybe you just need to set the cert permissions to 600

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems you're trying to deploy a .pem file as the public key of a SSH key-pair in `~azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` so you can use key-based authentication rather then password based ssh login, is that the case?

I normally associate PEM files with SSL certificates and you should note, in the words of the man page, that *SSH certificates are a different, and much simpler, format to the X.509 certificates used in SSL*. So using SSL certificates instead of SSH keys/certificates is going to fail.

Normally a private use SSH key-pair is created with `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f .ssh/mykey` which will create 2048 bit RSA private key file `~/.ssh/mykey` and the corresponding public key `~/.ssh/mykey.pub`. That public key needs to be deployed to `~azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Make sure that on the both your client and the server the `~/.ssh` directory is only accessible to the owner with `chmod 0700` and all the keyfiles are only readable for their owner i.e.   `chmod 0600`.

Further debugging ssh can be done from the client with `ssh -v -i ssh/mykey -p myport azureuser@myservice.cloudapp.net` or even more verbosely with `-vv`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using an "SSL" PEM file, or rather, an X509 PEM file, with RSA public key. While it is perfectly possible to use normal SSH keys as you describe, and which I am very familiar with, I was hoping that the deployment tools provided from Azure Manager supported the use case I described. That is, provision a VM from a template captured VM, using a new x509 PEM than the original.